# Google drive api with offline access

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

I am Using this following code for uploading files to google drive, using offline access api via refresh token:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
$client_id      = XXXX;
$client_secret  = XXXX;
$redirect_uri   = XXXX;
$refreshToken   = XXXX; //stored refresh token during the first time authendication

function get_oauth2_token($grantCode) 
{
global $config;

$client_id      = XXXX;
$client_secret  = XXXX;
$redirect_uri   = XXXX;

$oauth2token_url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
$clienttoken_post = array(
"client_id" => $client_id,
"client_secret" => $client_secret);

$clienttoken_post["refresh_token"] = $grantCode;
$clienttoken_post["grant_type"] = "refresh_token";

$curl = curl_init($oauth2token_url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $clienttoken_post);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
return $json_response;

}   
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/Drive.php';

$drive = new Google_Client();

$drive->setClientId($client_id); // HERE I WRITE MY Client ID
$drive->setClientSecret($client_secret); // HERE I WRITE MY Client Secret


$gdrive = new Google_Service_Drive($drive);
$response = get_oauth2_token($refreshToken);//i am getting the access token in json format here
$drive->setAccessToken($response);

$doc = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$doc->setTitle('Test Drive');
$doc->setDescription('Document');
$doc->setMimeType('text/plain');

$content = file_get_contents('files/example.txt');

$output = $gdrive->files->insert($doc, array(
  'data' => $content,
  'mimeType' => 'text/plain',
));

print_r($output);

?>
```

When I try to execute the above script, I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'The OAuth 2.0 access token has expired, and a refresh token is not available. Refresh tokens are not returned for responses that were auto-approved.' in D:\karthi\xampp-win32-1.8.2-1-VC9\xampp\htdocs\apis\google_drive\Google\Auth\OAuth2.php:222 Stack trace: #0 D:\karthi\xampp-win32-1.8.2-1-VC9\xampp\htdocs\apis\google_drive\Google\Service\Resource.php(176): Google_Auth_OAuth2->sign(Object(Google_Http_Request)) #1 D:\karthi\xampp-win32-1.8.2-1-VC9\xampp\htdocs\apis\google_drive\Google\Service\Drive.php(1754): Google_Service_Resource->call('insert', Array, 'Google_Service_...') #2 D:\karthi\xampp-win32-1.8.2-1-VC9\xampp\htdocs\apis\google_drive\offline.php(65): Google_Service_Drive_Files_Resource->insert(Object(Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile), Array) #3 {main} thrown in D:\karthi\xampp-  win32-1.8.2-1-VC9\xampp\htdocs\apis\google_drive\Google\Auth\OAuth2.php on line 222

I am using this php client library [GOOGLE PHP CLIENT](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)

Please help me.

Comment: I got same problem. I'll post here if I found any solution.